# Spring JDBC & MySQL - Getting EmptyResultDataAccessException when using queryForObject() but data exists

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

my code is:

```
    public AppMetaDBO getAppMetaRecord() throws SQLException {
    JdbcOperations jdbcOperations = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_APP_META;
    logger.config("Executing SQL query:[" + query + "]");
    return jdbcOperations.queryForObject(query, new AppMetaRowMapper());
}
```

Where **AppMetaRowMapper** is:

```
public class AppMetaRowMapper implements org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper<AppMetaDBO> {
@Override
public AppMetaDBO mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
    return new AppMetaDBO(resultSet.getDouble(COL_LAST_SUPPORTED_VER));
}
}
```

And **AppMetaDBO** is simply:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AppMetaDBO implements Serializable {
private double last_supported_version;
}
```

This throws a `EmptyResultDataAccessException`even though the DB table looks like this:

[image: MySQL Table]

It is important to note that the same server is able to **write** to the db with no issues, and even **read** from a different table with no issues.

The code that reads without issues is very similar and works fine:

```
UserDBO result = null;
    try {
        JdbcOperations jdbcOperations = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        String query = "SELECT *" + " FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE " + COL_UID + "=" + quote(uid);
        logger.config("Executing SQL query:[" + query + "]");
        result = jdbcOperations.queryForObject(query, new UserDboRowMapper());
    } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException ignored) {}
    return result;
```

Also important to note that the db server is not on a remote machine. In the local machine these issues are non-existent.

Please help I have absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What this logger prints?logger.config("Executing SQL query:[" + query + "]");

Comment: The SQL query: SELECT * FROM app_meta

Comment: Did you try `TABLE_APP_META = "sys.app_meta"` ?